# Redirect subdirectory to 404 page with status code

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http

I am trying to redirect a subset of pages that have been removed from a website to a specific 404 page using htaccess.

I currently have this rule in my htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^de/Engineering.*$ /error/ [R,L]
```

This works, but the url changes in the browser to error, which is bad for search engine bots, and the returned code is 302. I would like the url to remain the same (silent redirect) and the status code to change. The target page returns a correct 404 code so I need to pass that back through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `/error/` document already returns a `404` status code, you can just omit the [`R`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) flag

```
RewriteRule ^de/Engineering.*$ /error/ [L]
```

Comment: This is the problem though. There is no 404 originally. The system (big, old and developed by persons unknown) usually redirects to the homepage when a page is not found. I have been asked, after having removed a whole subdirectory (not physical, it was a category with a url attached) to redirect it to a 404 page.

Comment: @ravloony I hope, I understood the question this time. Please see updated answer.

Comment: Yes you have. Unfortunately this now does not redirect at all. I am not sure why.

Comment: @ravloony With `R` it redirects, without `R` it does a rewrite. Do you get any error message? What happens exactly?